# Android wrapping text with FlowTextView is overwriting TextView

Tags: android

I searched StackOverflow for a solution to wrap text around an image and found links to [FlowTextView](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView) with I have implemented but I am having an issue with it overwriting normal TextViews and the positioning of those TextViews. I did have them constrained to the end of the image but as that has now moved out of the layout I can no longer do that.

I want to get the FlowTextView to start where the 4th long TextView shows across the image and the TextViews to be to the right of the ImageView Can any help?

[image: textwrap]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView
            android:id="@+id/ftv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_room"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/room_image"
                android:padding="4dp" />

        </uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_room_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/ftv"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
            android:text="@string/living_room"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_length"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textview_room_name"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ftv"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/length_12_x_6"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_width"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textview_length"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ftv"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/width_10_x_8" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textview_width"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ftv"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"                                                                               android:text="@string/with_a_large_window_looking_onto_the_vast_garden" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ftv"`. `layout_alignEnd` puts the end of both the views together instead of start to end.